# How to determine proceeds for an individual in-app purchase transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Is it possible to determine your proceeds (amount of money deposited in your bank account) for an individual transaction?

In the app at the time of purchase you can get a product’s `price` but it is localized to the user’s currency. Server-side in the validated receipt object each item in `in_app` contains `product_id` so you can know which product they purchased but it doesn’t provide a tier or price.

I understand the proceeds amount depends on which tier was selected for that product at the time of purchase, any taxes and adjustments applied and the currency exchange rate at the time of the deposit if purchased with a currency other than that of your bank account, and of course Apple takes their cut. Payments and Financial Reports gives you your combined proceeds for each country/region, but I don’t see it broken down by transaction.

We’re implementing the ability to tip digital content creators in our app via consumable IAPs, so we need to record for each transaction how much money we owe that creator. We don’t want to send them more money than Apple deposited into our bank account. lol So we need a way to know how much was deposited for this transaction, preferably programmatically (maybe using the App Store Connect API?) or if we can manually generate a report that lists transaction ids and proceeds in that month that would work. That’ll allow us to distribute the correct amount owed to the creators by looking up each transaction we recorded in the database.

If this isn't possible, we believe we need to store the date purchased, localized price paid, and locale for each transaction. When money is deposited, generate a report, get the transactions in that date range, for each one look up the taxes/adjustments and exchange rate for that locale, and manually calculate the proceeds. `((price * 0.7) + tax and adjustments) * exchange rate` An unknown here is the 30% cut Apple takes, is that calculated before or after the conversion to USD? I think before. Is there a way to get the proceeds amount for the price the user paid rather than hardcode 30%? This can change over time though right. Seems error prone and not a good approach but maybe this is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to know exactly. This is especially true for consumable purchases since there's no way for you to detect a refund.

I know some other apps have built a "content creator tipping system" by creating a unique product Id in App Store Connect for each creator, then don't pay them out until the financial reports come out and you can see exactly how much money you received from their product. (Better from a business cashflow perspective to not pay them until the money is in your bank anyway).

Comment: Oh can consumables be refunded? I thought only non-consumables could be. 

Comment: I've never tried it myself. If they show up in the https://reportaproblem.apple.com/ receipts list then you should be able to.